# Universal home DNS

Tags: networking, dns, mdns

I have many network devices at home and I would like to have them accessible on network in human-friendly way. I do not want the devices to be accessible directly from the internet.

My needs:

1. **Device can have multiple "aliases"** - eg. it should be accessible under either `backup`, `docker` or `nas` name

   - Because I am running multiple services on single device and like to distinguish them, with the option to move them to another device
2. **Device should be accessible from remote using home-hosted VPN**

   - Because I would like to access my NAS and be able to run backups from remote location
3. **Device should be accessible from home workstation connected to work VPN**

   - Because I work from home sometimes and still want to access my local network

Over the years I have tried the following solutions. However none of them fulfills all my needs without compromises.

### Using `mDNS`

This was my initial setup, devices are accessible under `hostname.local`

###### ❓ Device can have multiple "aliases"

It might be possible to have multiple mDNS names per device, however I have never investigated it further due to the following issue

###### ❌ Device should be accessible from remote using home-hosted VPN

The `mDNS` protocol is using `broadcast` which is not forwarded over VPN connection. The `mDNS` responses from devices can not reach the VPN client.

###### ✅ Device should be accessible from home workstation connected to work VPN

This works OK because the `mDNS` "bypasses" VPN and accesses local network.

### Using `mDNS` over home `DNS` server

I am hosting my own `DNS` server at home. The idea is that this should solve my first two needs. However having `*.local` records in `DNS` server is not recommended. For example `dig` outputs warning

```bash
$ dig docker.local
...
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
...
```

###### ✅ Device can have multiple "aliases"

Even though it is not recommended the names resolve correctly.

###### ✅ Device should be accessible from remote using home-hosted VPN

The `DNS` server is accessed in the simple request-response manner so it is fully compatible with VPN.

###### ❌ Device should be accessible from home workstation connected to work VPN

This does not work because the workstation is using work DNS inside VPN which (obviously) has no records for my `docker.local`.

### Using home `DNS` server with custom home-only domain

This should be "the way to go". I have created my home domain eg. `myplace` (to avoid shady `*.home`) and let the DHCP server to set this domain to all devices. The idea was to  use the `DNS` server properly.

###### ✅ Device can have multiple "aliases"

Thanks to `DNS` server.

###### ✅ Device should be accessible from remote using home-hosted VPN

The `DNS` server is accessed in the simple request-response manner so it is fully compatible with VPN.

###### ❌ Device should be accessible from home workstation connected to work VPN

This does not work because the workstation is using work DNS inside VPN which (obviously) has no records for my `docker.myplace`.

### Using public `DNS` server with public domain (so far only theoretical)

I also pay for public domain, let it be `example.com`. The idea is to fix the third need from previous solution by having eg. `docker.example.com = 192.168.0.17` record in the public `DNS`.

###### ✅ Device can have multiple "aliases"

Thanks to `DNS` server.

###### ✅ Device should be accessible from remote using home-hosted VPN

The `DNS` server is accessed in the simple request-response manner so it is fully compatible with VPN.

###### ✅ Device should be accessible from home workstation connected to work VPN

Since the public domain is hosted on public `DNS` server the `docker.example.com` should be resolvable from anywhere (like the `superuser.com` domain).

⚠️ However. This is insecure:

1. I would expose all my device names and their (home) IP addresses to the internet
2. When accessing `docker.example.com` from outside the home network (at work, cafe etc.) I would be connecting to `192.168.0.17` in **their** local network. This could end up in different ways

   - address does not exist - connection simply fails
   - address exists - I would be connecting to someone's device, which could be very dangerous (eg. for insecure connections)

**Does anyone have better idea how to do this?**

Comment: While I applaud your dedication in presenting all of this information, I wonder if any of it could be simplified or summarized? This is NOT a "wall of text", but it does feel like a lot of information, and SOME of the formatting choices may be breaking things up too much. Also, what about split tunneling to get your work traffic over the VPN, and the other traffic is kept outside the VPN and thus unaffected by it?

Comment: I think OP's showing their work, so to speak.

Comment: In theory, using a slightly more obscure subnet for your home network would semi-help with someone else using the same subdomain for a lan. Nearly everyone uses 192.168.(0/1).x - something like the carving a chunk out of the 10.0.0.x block might work well enough to prevent casual collisions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This does not work because the workstation is using work DNS inside VPN which (obviously) has no records for my docker.myplace.

Internal home DNS would work if your OS had support for split DNS. For example, with systemd-resolved on Linux, there are multiple sets of <domains, DNS servers> (one per network interface), so that you can have VPN DNS servers for work domains but home DNS for everything else – or vice versa, home DNS for ".home.arpa" but VPN DNS for everything else. Before systemd, it was also possible to set up dnsmasq or Unbound to achieve the same.

(Not to be confused with "split-brain" or "split-view" DNS, which is a server-side thing.)

Windows appears to call this "conditional forwarding" in its DNS server software, and *might* support it for the built-in VPN client (IKEv2), although corporate VPNs are probably unlikely to allow it.

> I would expose all my device names and their (home) IP addresses to the internet

Is that *actually* an issue, though? Device names are, well, names – they don't strike me as an inherently private thing (though perhaps I have a somewhat old-school view of it, from back when this used to be a quite common thing to do with home networks); and the IP addresses have no meaning outside your home LAN anyway.

You can always have a mix of both, though: have public DNS names (perhaps generic names like `docker`) for the select few devices that you need to access from the Work Workstation, but use internal DNS for everything else. It is possible to configure more than one domain suffix in most PCs (and even deploy a list via DHCP).

> When accessing docker.example.com from outside the home network (at work, cafe etc.) I would be connecting to 192.168.0.17 in their local network. This could end up in different ways

IPv6 would be the usual "solution" for that; a randomly generated private IPv6 prefix would have ~56 unique bits which is usually more than enough to avoid any collision.

Comment: Awesome, thousand thanks for your help! The split-DNS (which I did not know about) was the answer. I was able to redirect my home `myplace` domain to my home DNS and the rest is forwarded to work DNS. I used this specifically https://coredns.io/manual/toc/#forwarding-domains-to-different-upstreams